# Connecting to a specific server that is behind the balancer with C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have a balancer with 6 servers behind.
When I make a `HttpWebRequest` any of these servers can resolve.
What I need is to test the response time of each server by calling the same URL, but specifying the server to respond (I need to try each of the servers, making the same call).

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What type of load balancer is running? What type of servers? What is the config of the LB (sticky sessions, round robin etc)?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to try each of the servers, making the same call

That totally depends on how the load balancer is configured. If you fire six requests, it may very well happen that each of those requests is handled by the same server.

Call each of the servers directly, or look at the load balancer's documentation on how to make a request to a specific server behind that balancer, for example using a certain request header.